# Lighter web server for redirects

Tags: performance, apache, nginx, lighttpd

I know Apache, Nginx and Lighttpd.

Does anyone have benchmark for just redirecting purposes ?

I have a bunch of "subdomains" pointing to one IP, and this IP (with the webserver installed) will redirect with a very simple rules (available in all three) to other places ...

My question is more about performance, if anyone knows that any of those 3 (or other) is the best to support millions of "just redirecting" rules.

thank you

Comment: I guess, that with simple redirecting, you'll be first limited with network than server performance.

Comment: Both performance and capacity for this kiond of task will still be strongly related to the nature of the ioneraction and the configuration of the server. But with "millions" of lines of logic, it would be far more efficient and manageable to implement at the logic tier.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explained myself ... there will be "millions" of requests, not rules ;-)

Comment: servers as a software have no issues, hardware will be your problem, especially the network interface. you need to do your own tests, because no one knows your configuration.